# LinkedIn JSAPI calls after REST Oauth2 authentication

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

LinkedIn documentation say:

> While the easiest method of authenticating a user for the JSAPI is to use one of the login buttons, some sites have implemented the OAuth 1.0a flow used by the REST API.  Whichever type of authentication you use for the user, the JSAPI will recognize that the member has already logged in, as long as the key and hostname are the same.  This happens automatically, requiring no additional code by the developer.

It mentions Oauth1 but then says "**Whichever** type of authentication you use (...)".

I would like to authenticate the user through Oauth2 and then make JSAPI calls (**without** asking the user to authenticate again). I tried to retrieve the profile through JSAPI after a rest oauth2 authentication (rails/omniauth):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: KEY
authorize: true
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", testLinkedin);
}

function testLinkedin() {
  IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(result) { console.log(result.values[0]); });
}
</script>
```

The problem is that this API Profile call result is undefined, even though calling "IN.User.isAuthorized()" returns true. The call in the example gives `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections 404 (Not Found)`.
The weirdest thing is that sometimes it works, for a little bit, after I authenticate and try to make the calls - but 10 minutes later it's returning undefined again.

This is not a permissions problem - I have the correct permissions and am able to make the same call through REST.
Has anyone been able to make JSAPI calls after authenticating with REST oauth2?

Comment: IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);